# Finding text file from user input in c

Tags: c, text, fopen, txt

There are multiple .txt files in a folder like;

math.txt

physics.txt

programming.txt

User must enter lesson's name and then program should open .txt file and read it.
The problem is I can't use a variable in fopen() function.

`FILE *lesson= fopen("...\\lessons\\[user input].txt","r");`

any idea?

Comment: *Why* can't you use a variable created by `sprintf()`? Is it a problem constraint, or did it fail?

Comment: Do not forget to check the user input! You may want to throw an error if it contains "..". Otherwise the user could "escape" the lessons directory and access files they should not access.

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think you can't use a variable in `fopen()`?

Try this:

```
#define PATH_STRING "...\\lessons"

//Allocate enough memory for the whole filepath
char *buffer = malloc(strlen(PATH_STRING) + strlen(argv[index]) + 6);

//Write the path into the buffer
sprintf(buffer,"%s\\%s.txt", PATH_STRING, argv[index]);

//Pass the pointer to the buffer as an argument of fopen()
FILE *fp = fopen(buffer,"r");

free(buffer);
```

Comment: It is recommended to use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`. The magic number `7` is incorrect, but by chance it is larger than needed :)